# $10$ people ($6$ male, $4$ female) divided into $2$ equal groups: what is the probability that all females are in the same group?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> This question comes from a completed, marked, and returned exam. It will not likely be reused.

#### Problem

As stated in the question above

#### Work

First, I note that there are $\binom{10}{5}$ possible groupings.

Second, I note that, if all $4$ females are in the same group, then the remaining fifth member is one of the boys: there are $\binom{6}{1} = 6$ ways to choose the fifth member.

So I conclude $\Pr = \frac{6}{\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{1}{42}$.

#### Question

I was marked incorrect: the given answer is $\frac{1}{21}$, or exactly twice my answer.

What reasoning led to this conclusion? Why does it seem like some sort of symmetry argument allows us to conclude there are $12$ ways to choose the fifth member?

Comment: Note that  $\frac{6}{\binom{10}{5}} = \frac{6}{252} = \frac{1}{42}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig apologies i was looking at the answers on the question below as i typed

Comment: Another way to see that there are only $126$ possible groups is to observe that if Eloise is one of the four girls, then there are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to select which four of the other members are in her group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've double-counted the groupings:  $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ and $\{F, G, H, I, J\}$ is the same grouping as  $\{F, G, H, I, J\}$ and $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$.  Accounting for this double-count, there are $\frac{1}{2} \binom{10}{5}$ distinct groupings.  (This is probably the most-common counting mistake of all time.  Everyone makes it at least once.)

Comment: Those who make it *only* once don't do much math.

Comment: @saulspatz  lol true.